# My old passport expired and was unused. As an Indian citizen, would I need it while applying for a visa to Japan in Taiwan?

Tags: visas, japan, taiwan

I am an Indian citizen. My old passport was valid till about 10 years back. I never used it for any travel or document proofs at all. My current passport is valid till another 3 years with two visits to the US and two to Singapore. I live in Taiwan and have been working here for about a year now. Next month, I'll be doing a short tourist trip to Japan. Would I need my old passport while I apply for a visa?

My old passport is in India at the moment, and ideally I want to apply for the visa right away. So if it's unnecessary to show the old one, I'll save the shipping time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope.  For new visas, you only ever need your active, current passport - specifically (if you have two or more citizenships), the passport you intend to travel to the country (in this case Japan) on.

You may be asked for other documentation - e.g. proof of funds, accommodation and so on, but you won't need the past passports. They're considered invalid documents for the purpose of acquiring a visa.

Edit: Included [visahq link for Indian citizens living in Taiwan applying for a visa to Japan](https://japan.visahq.com/requirements/India/resident-Taiwan).

Comment: If your visa application depends on proving your recent travel history, you might need to submit a recently-expired passport as evidence.

Comment: @phoog do we know of a country that does this? I've certainly not been everywhere, but the most I've had to do was simply list countries I'd visited, with dates.  No evidence required.

Comment: Regardless, this is for Japan, and at least one of their [embassy pages](https://japan.visahq.com/requirements/India/resident-United_States/) specifically says only the current passport, although I will allow it does say 'may ask for extra documents at their discretion', which would be unfortunate :/

Comment: 'Do we know of a country that does this?' Umm, certainly we do. UK and most Schengen countries do. The last time I filed application for a Spanish visa, for instance, there even was the requirement to not only provide all my old passports but also to make photocopies of every page in them that had had any kind of marks. The whole pack of the application contained somewhere around 30 A4 sheets of paper.

Comment: @AndreyChernyakhovskiy wow, ouch! TIL!